# Cloud functions for firebase generation 2

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How can I implement firestore database trigger (onCreate, onUpdate) with Cloud functions for firebase gen 2 ?

As in Firestore cloud function gen1 we can use Cloud firestore database triggers, But how can we implement this in Firestore cloud function gen 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am successfully listening for events from `Firestore v2` via `Gen 2 Functions`. You can give something like below a try in your `index.js` if using Node.js Functions.

```
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
const {onDocumentUpdated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

initializeApp();

exports.myUpdateFunc = 
    onDocumentUpdated('/myCollectionName/{myDocId}', (event) => {
        const old_doc = event.data.before.data();
        const new_doc = event.data.after.data();
        const id =  event.params.myDocId;

        // do something
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will check this.

Comment: @MohanishSaim I haven't used it, but I would assume that `event` contains auth data. Maybe give `event.auth` a try and report back?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta), Cloud functions gen 2 do not support Cloud Firestore triggers at the moment.

You'll have to use Gen 1 functions if your application rely on Firestore triggers.

Comment: Is it possible to 1st Gen just for Firebase Authentication triggers, and in the same project use 2nd Gen for other Firestore triggers? (since Firestore triggers seem to be supported now?)

Answer (score 2):

Firestore Triggers for Cloud Functions 2nd Gen are now in Public Preview.

You can view the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions-2nd-gen